# mongoose query to return products that are linked to a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to node, express and mongoose.

I am working on my first study app to get the knowledge required to build a real node.js application.

In my application I have a Products model (mongoose) like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    , config = require('../../config/config')[env]
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    address: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    user: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})

/**
 * Validations
 */

ProductSchema.path('name').validate(function (name) {
    return name.length > 0
}, 'Product name cannot be blank')

ProductSchema.methods = {


}


/**
 * Statics
 */
ProductSchema.statics = {
    list: function (options, cb) {
        var criteria = options.criteria || {}
        this.find(criteria)
            .populate('user', 'name username')
            .sort({'createdAt': -1}) // sort by date
            .limit(options.perPage)
            .skip(options.perPage * options.page)
            .exec(cb)
    },

}

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

As you can see there is a user property. I am using a middleware layer for Facebook login and that all works

My Controller looks like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Product = mongoose.model('Product')
    , utils = require('../../lib/utils')
    , _ = require('underscore')


//Create new product
exports.new = function(req, res){
    res.render('products/new', {
        title: 'New Product',
        product: new Product({})
    })
}


exports.create= function (req, res) {
    console.log('product.create');
    var product = new Product(req.body)
    product.user = req.user
    product.save()
    res.render('home')
}
exports.show = function(req, res){
    var product = Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            //return res.send(product);
            console.log('product.show in controller'+product);
            res.render('products/show', {
                title: product.name,
                product: product
            })
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });

}

exports.edit = function (req, res) {
    var product = Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('product.edit in controller'+product);
            res.render('products/edit', {
                title: 'Edit ' + product.name,
                product: product
            })
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}

exports.update = function(req, res){
    console.log('product.update in controller');
    var product = Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            product = _.extend(product, req.body)
            product.save()
            res.render('/products')
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });

}

exports.destroy = function(req, res){
    var product = Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('product.destroy in controller'+product);
            product.remove(function(err){
                req.flash('info', 'Deleted successfully')
                res.redirect('/products')
            })
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });

}

exports.index = function(req, res){
    var page = (req.param('page') > 0 ? req.param('page') : 1) - 1
    var perPage = 30
    var options = {
        perPage: perPage,
        page: page
    }

    Product.list(options, function(err, products) {
        if (err) return res.render('500')
        Product.count().exec(function (err, count) {
            res.render('products/index', {
                title: 'Product',
                products: products,
                page: page + 1,
                pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
            })
        })
    })
}
//personal
exports.me = function(req, res){
    console.log('product.me in controller'+req.user);
    var page = (req.param('page') > 0 ? req.param('page') : 1) - 1
    var perPage = 30
    var userFilter = ('user:"529f227374d410eb4e000001" ')
    var options = {
        perPage: perPage,
        page: page,
        user: userFilter
    }
    console.log('product.me options  '+userFilter);
    Product.listMe(options, function(err, products) {
        if (err) return res.render('500')
        Product.count().exec(function (err, count) {
            res.render('products/index', {
                title: 'Product',
                products: products,
                page: page + 1,
                pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

My problem is that i want to return only Products for the logged in user.

So the route is:

```
app.get('/products/me', products.me)
```

Problem is the export.me, I don't know how to configure this so I will receive only products for the logged in user

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why are you again counting? when products itself is an array. You can get the count via length(products)

```
Product.list(options, function(err, products) {
        if (err) return res.render('500')
            res.render('products/index', {
                title: 'Product',
                products: products,
                page: page + 1,
                pages: Math.ceil(products.length/ perPage)
            })
 })
```